# R version 3.5.0 Windows For Loop read csv not reading file correctly

Tags: r, for-loop, read.csv

I have a folder (specdata) with a tonne of csv files. 
When I run my function to read individual files, i have no issue.
but when I add in a For loop so that the function can take Function(1:10) file names, it won't recognise that there are 10 files.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory = "specdata", pollutant = "sulfate", id = 
"001") {
pollutantcount <- 0
pollutantsum <- 0

filetype <- ".csv"
pathswitch <- "."


file_len <- nchar(id)
if (file_len == 1) {
new_id <- paste("00", id, filetype, sep = "")}
else if (file_len == 2) {
new_id <- paste("0", id, filetype, sep = "")}
else
new_id <- paste(id, filetype, sep = "")
new_path <-  file.path(pathswitch,directory, new_id)
new_data <- read.csv(new_path)
pollutantsum <- pollutantsum + sum(new_data[,pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
pollutantcount <- pollutantcount + length(na.exclude(new_data[,pollutant])) 
meanofpollutant <- (pollutantsum / pollutantcount) 
print(meanofpollutant)
```

}

I should specify that the code is written above to recognise if the file id 001.csv is entered in arg as 1 or 01, it will write correct file name for reading.

I've searched for hours but I can't get an example where I understand how the For loop is reading csv file names clearly.
If anyone could suggest an edit I'd appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `list.files(path = "specdata", pattern = ".csv$")` to identify your files? Constructing these filepaths looks overly complicated for the task to me...

Comment: @JonGrub thanks. I wasn't sure that would help.  I know it returns a vector of names of files in specdata, but how does this link with the argument 1:10, where filenames = 001.csv, 002.csv...?  Do you think this would help the read.csv in the loop?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `for` loop.

```
files <- list.files(path = "specdata", pattern = ".csv$")
# Since you build this up you first need a starting value
pollutantsum <- 0
pollutantcount <- 0
# Use the files argument as the 'seq' argument
for (file in files) {
  new_data <- read.csv(file)
  pollutantsum <- pollutantsum + sum(new_data[,pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)
  pollutantcount <- pollutantcount + length(na.exclude(new_data[,pollutant])) 
  meanofpollutant <- (pollutantsum / pollutantcount)
}
```

This is a classic example of an inefficient `for` loop though as you slowly build up pollutantsum and pollutantcount, forcing R to move around data on every iteration of the loop.

A more efficient way would be to use `lapply()` to read files in and then perform the operations on the list object. This would be roughly, how you would accomplish that:

```
files <- list.files(path = "specdata", pattern = ".csv$")
files.list <- lapply(files, read.csv)
pollutantsum <- sum(sapply(files.list, function(x) sum(x[, pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)))
pollutantsum <- sum(sapply(files.list, function(x) length(na.exclude(x[,pollutant]))))
meanofpollutant <- (pollutantsum / pollutantcount)
```

Note, that since you did not provide sample data, I was not able to test this.

Comment: thanks @JonGrub. I had to use the first option for ease of use but intend to use the efficient one in future.  getting Nan in print but right result in debug data, but I'll figure it out :)